# The return type 'HomePage' isn't a 'Future<void>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making pattern shape lock function. I'm stuck in the problem that when the pattern is successes it has to go HomePage() that I made in another file. so I implemented return HomePage() in if block below. but It occurs error that

> The return type 'HomePage' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's context.

How Can I work arrange this?

```
if (pattern != null) ...[
        SizedBox(height: 16),
        MaterialButton(
          color: Colors.green,
          child:
          Text("Check Pattern", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () async {
            final result = await Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              "/check_pattern",
              arguments: pattern,
            );
            if (result == true) {
              context.replaceSnackbar(
                content: Text(
                  "it's correct",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                ),
              );
              return HomePage();
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

`onPressed` method is void,`void Function();` doesnt return widget. If you like to navigate new routine based on condition, you can wrap with `Navigator.of(context).push`

replace `return HomePage();` with

```dart
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => HomePage(),
    ));
```